# Switch content from page 1 to page 2 if page1 is full HTML

Tags: html

I'm making a website which has 5-10+ pages, each page can have 10 divs. When I put 11 divs on my site (page 1) I want the oldest of the divs to move over to page 2, and when page 2 has more than 10 divs, the oldest divs are moved to page 3 etc.

Basically like a forum, each page can have a certain amount of posts, when there are more posts than the page can contain, the older posts are moved to page 2, 3, 4 …

**Right now, what I've done is make 10 copies of my page and I thought I'd manually update them, delete/copy old content from page 1, put in page 2, delete/copy old content from page 2, paste in page 3 and so on. That isn't very efficient … or efficient at all.**

I searched on Google but don't seem to get any hits related to what I'm wanting to do, the word page isn't very search friendly …

I've considered doing this with iframes but I already have a piece of `<iframe>` and it loads a quarter of a second later than the rest of content. There must be a better way, I just don't know how to find it by searching Google.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `pagination`

Comment: HTML and CSS are not going to be enough for what you're trying to do. At a *minimum*, you need some JavaScript to handle the pagination. A (much) better solution would be to use some sort of Content Management System, e.g. WordPress, Drupal, etc.

Comment: Thanks for edit. I've come across pagination and I always got results of wordpress on google, I thought it was a webmaking tool, silly me. Thanks guys, Ill look into that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called pagination. You need learn about PHP (Server side programming) to create HTML dynamically based on your data (Learn more about database, I suggest MySQL).

Here the concept :

- PHP get the data from database.
- PHP creating HTML dynamically based on data.
- We are limitting the data to 10 for each page and create a link to show next 10 items (read about pagination).

You can also create pagination without PHP which means all data in one page but somehow make it looks like several pages. (learn about pagination using CSS and javascript)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for, I'll look into it and try get a better grasp of it :).

Comment: Yes, if you rally concern about creating web application. PHP is great starting point. If this is about homework problem. Try make the data in onepage and somehow hide it which make it look like go to another page. (this is need javascript and maybe css)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize there was more to it than a little javascript and html. Big surprise for me :P Now I gotta go and learn some PHP and stuff haha, thx :)